# formula derivation regarding conditional distribution in brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the intuitive meaning of $K_1, K_2, K_3$ in regards to the conditional density formula derivation in Brownian motion.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249707/what-is-the-intuitive-meaning-of-k-1-k-2-k-3-in-regards-to-the-conditional-d)

The image below shows that when the process goes A->B, 
there should be a $$-B^2\over2(t-s)$$

Somehow, Part B doesn't include it. I can't seem to understand why. Is it because somehow it's built into K2?
If so, what's the terminology called for K1-3? Am i missing a mathematically concept here?

Thanks!!

**The excerpt is as below**

Suppose we require the conditional distribution of X(s) given that X(t) = B where s < t.

The conditional density is:

[image]

where K1, K2, K3 do not depend of x.